# Path not added to $PATH variable when executing a command

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables, psycopg2

First of all, the context of this question is: [Cannot install psycopg2 on OSX 10.6.7 with XCode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427157/cannot-install-psycopg2-on-osx-10-6-7-with-xcode4)

So I am trying to execute the following:

```
$PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" pip install psycopg2
```

however, I get the following:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin: No such file or directory
```

Basically, I need to add '/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin' to $PATH, so that the rest of the command can be executed as it needs something from that directory.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables being assigned to shouldn't have a `$`.

```
PATH=...
```

Comment: so it should be 'PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin ...'?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: You should not be using `export` when invoking a command like this.

Answer (score 1):

Issue this commnad:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: See the comment on the other similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, remove the $ as already mentioned.  You might also need the -E option to sudo, or to change the env_reset setting in sudoers.  You also can specify environment variables after sudo.

```
sudo -E PATH="..." ARCH="..." pip install whatever
```