# Error pip install psycopg2 on osx

Tags: macos, virtualenv, pip, psycopg2

I'm attempting to install `psycopg2` in a virtualenv via `pip install psycopg2`, and receive the following error: https://gist.github.com/pjhoberman/5347708.

I attempted the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427157/cannot-install-psycopg2-on-osx-10-6-7-with-xcode4), but received the same error.

I'm on OSX 10.7.5, Python 2.7.3, GCC 4.2.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the libpq installed